# Amazon S3 Private Bucket Display Many User Images

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am trying to figure out the best way to display many private user images. I am building an Instagram clone as a practice app to learn S3 and other AWS services.

There are many tutorials on displaying a single image from a private s3 bucket using pre-signed URLs but I can't find resources to do this at scale.

**Questions:**

**1A.**
If I am creating a photo gallery of thumbnails that pulls down 20-50 (or more) images at a time, does that mean I need to make 20-50+ pre-signed URL requests for each of those images? Making one request per image just seems like a lot.

**1B.**
If I do have to create pre-signed URLs is it best to do this on the frontend or backend? AWS SDK allows for this to be done on either side but which approach is best?

**1C.**
Lastly, if creating pre-signed URLs is the best way to approach this, what are best practices for expiration length and caching images? Any idea on how Instagram or other popular image sharing websites approach this?

**Alternative solution to pre-signed URLs that I've found:**

**2.**
Create an IAM role for the backend, have the BE download the private images from s3 then serve them to the front end. This seems like an expensive operation but the only alternative I found.

Comment: 1A - you give out 50 urls to 50 images anyway, should not make difference if those URLs are presigned urls or not. 1B - if the frontend can generate those urls then what would be the point, the frontend must only see permitted content, the backend is the one to permit it. 1C - depens on your usecase. 2. CloudFront with Lambda@Edge: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-using-cookies-protect-your-amazon-cloudfront-content-from-being-downloaded-by-unauthenticated-users/